# Waiting For Process To Complete

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio-2010, process

Is there any way to pause a process or wait unitl the process is complete before continuing onto the next line of code?

Here is my current process to zip all PDFs and then delete. Currently, its deleting files before the zipping is complete. Is there a way to pause/wait until the process is complete?

```
    Dim psInfo As New System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("C:\Program Files\7-Zip\7z.exe ", Arg1 + ZipFileName + PathToPDFs)
    psInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden
    System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psInfo)

    'delete remaining pdfs
    For Each foundFile As String In My.Computer.FileSystem.GetFiles("C:\Temp\", FileIO.SearchOption.SearchAllSubDirectories, "*.pdf")
        File.Delete(foundFile)
    Next
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can use `process.WaitForExit` method

WaitForExit can make the current thread wait until the associated process to exit.

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 15):

[Process.Start](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0w4h05yb.aspx) returns a *Process* instance. As others have mentioned, you can use the [WaitForExit()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/fb4aw7b8.aspx) method, although you should probably use [WaitForExit(Integer)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ty0d8k56.aspx), which includes a timeout for just in case something goes wrong with the zipping process.

So your code would become something like:

```
...
Dim zipper As System.Diagnostics.Process = System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(psInfo)
Dim timeout As Integer = 60000 '1 minute in milliseconds

If Not zipper.WaitForExit(timeout) Then
    'Something went wrong with the zipping process; we waited longer than a minute
Else
    'delete remaining pdfs
    ...
End If
```

Answer (score 4):

There are several WaitForExit methods available.

Check out [Process.WaitForExit](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.waitforexit.aspx).

> `WaitForExit()` makes the current thread wait until the associated
>   process terminates. It should be called after all other methods are
>   called on the process. To avoid blocking the current thread, use the
>   [Exited](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.process.exited?view=netframework-4.7.2) event.
>
> - Instructs the Process component to wait indefinitely for the
>     associated process to exit.
>
> `WaitForExit(Int32)` makes the current thread wait until the
>   associated process terminates. It should be called after all other
>   methods are called on the process. To avoid blocking the current
>   thread, use the Exited event.
>
> - Instructs the Process component to wait the specified number of
>     milliseconds for the associated process to exit.