# How to use WaitForExit()

Tags: vb.net

I'm trying to run Autodesk Inventor deployment image using

```
Process.Start()
```

and then using

```
WaitForExit()
```

perform another operation after the installation is done.

This is not working because deployment image runs on two occasions.
First "setup initialization" which is collecting various required informations and second "installing software" that actually performs the installation.

Both occasions have their own process (setup.exe) in taskmanager with its own unique PID and my problem is that WaitForExit triggers after the "setup initialization" is completed.

Any suggestion how to handle this properly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Waiting For Process To Complete](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12603279/waiting-for-process-to-complete)

Comment: Nope. My problem is of a different type.